# JpaRepository findAll() returns List of Objects but fields are set to null (CLOSED)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

## [Closed]

When calling the `findAll()` function from the `JpaRepository` I correctly get a list of the wanted Objects.

When inspecting the list, one can see that all the fields in an Object are set to `null`.

[image]

Checking the Database alle fields are set. Using `findAll()` on other Entities works perfectly fine.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "loc_module")
public class LocModule implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "filename", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String filename;

    @Size(max = 2048)
    @Column(name = "path", length = 2048)
    private String path;

    @ManyToOne
    private LocOutputType outputType;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "modules")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<LocKey> keys = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocModule name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public LocModule filename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
        return this;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public LocModule path(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        return this;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public LocOutputType getOutputType() {
        return outputType;
    }

    public LocModule outputType(LocOutputType locOutputType) {
        this.outputType = locOutputType;
        return this;
    }
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi can you who us the complete code please ? may be it is a configuration problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This might be a stupid question but are the values `null` or are they "null" (the 4 letters string) ?

Comment: Is `loc_module` a database view, by any chance?

Comment: did you override the toString method of LocModule? is the data null only during inspect or also in your UI?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was finally solved and sadly it was completely out of my control.

Since I was Testing this on a Testing Environment somehow, someone copied the data one the table `LocTable` in form another table, without my knowledge.

The foreign key set for `LocOutputType` was therefor referring to a non existing `LocOutputType`.

Liquibase was then not able to map the rest of the Object.
Weirdly I did not get any sort of error message.

This is very stupid and I should somehow have seen it.

I will mark the question as closed.